# How to set up a dedicated administrator screen in react native app

Tags: react-native, sqlite

In react app, an administrator can have a dedicated domain separate from the public user.
The administrator can have access to the database to download tables e.g. list of all users,  contact us messages
In my react native app, I use sqlite. I find it difficult to separate administrator screen from public users screen

Below is what I have and I don't like it because I have not come across such before:

App.js

```
export default function App() {    
const [selector, setSelector] = useState();
// some codes ...

return (
    <>
        <StatusBar style={'dark'} />        
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.rootScreen}>
        {!selector && <UserSelector onUserOption={selectorHandler} />}
        { selector === "public" && 
            <PublicScreen 
            onLogout={()=> setSelector()} 
            onConfirmedRestart={()=> setSelector()}
            />
        }
        { selector === "admin" && 
            <AdminHomeScreen 
            onLogout={()=> setSelector()} 
            onConfirmedRestart={()=> setSelector()}
            />
        }            
        </SafeAreaView>
    </>
)
```

};

The help I need is any of these:
Either separate Public screen from Admin screen so there will be no need for a selector
Or any other method for the administrator to access sqlite database and download tables in the database

Comment: Are you using a local sqlite? If so, the administrator would need access to the users device. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: No. Access to sqlite server where all database are stored. With this, the administrator can get the list of all users of the app, download all messages from the public, etc. all from the various tables in the app database

Comment: Why would you want administrators to use the app then? Build a website that accesses the remote database via an API and let administrators do their work there.

Comment: Exactly. I am working on this Thanks